# How do I solve this Numpy slicing question?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I'm having trouble trying to wrap my head around this question on slicing with Numpy.

Q- what is the output of 'out' when running the following code?

```
X=np.array([[1,0,1],[2,2,2]]) 

out=X[0,1:3]
```

I know running this code returns 0,1. However just trying to solve this myself I'm landing on 1,2. The way i understood it, X[0,1:3] means to start from row 0 and end on row 1; accessing column 3. When i do this however, i land on 1,2.

I guess my question is, how does one land on 0,1?

thank you

Comment: Have you run this code ? Because it is returning array([0, 1])

Comment: When you have indexing questions, see this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: "I keep coming up with 1,2 instead of 0,1." Well, what is your reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

`X`:

```py
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

In `X[0, 1:3]`:

- the first value - **0**, tells which row to select:  `[1, 0, 1]`,
- the second value - a slice `1:3` tells which columns to select: **1st** and **2nd**.

  (in slices the start is included, and the end is not - so **1** is included, and **3** is not - that’s why we get 1, 2).

The **1st** and **2nd** colums of `[1, 0, 1]` are `[0, 1]`
(because indexing in Python starts at **0**).

Answer (score -1):

when you are referencing 2d numpy arrays, the text before the comma refers to the first index, the vertical index, and the text after refers to the second index, the horizontal index. Further, a range X:Y always returns the data between X and Y-1.

In this case, [0,] indicates you want row 0, and [1:3] indicates you want the data between columns 1 & 2, or [0,1]. To get [1,2] from your data you can do:

```
out = X[0:2,0]
```

Which indicates you want rows 0 through 1, and column 0.